# ('En' Replacing The 'de' Part Of A Noun) What's the meaning of 'en' in: Encore un banalité, bien que l'auteur en soit Boileau!

Tags: en

I know the various uses of 'en' but it's really hard to know why it's used here:

> *Encore une banalité, bien que l'auteur **en** soit Boileau!*

Is this an idomatic expression with 'être'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special with this expression, ***en*** refers to the ***banalité*** :

> *Encore une banalité, bien que l'auteur **de la banalité** soit Boileau !*